# Generators for the solution set of a system of inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, systems-of-equations

Given a system of linear equations of the form
\begin{align*}
a_{1,1}x_1+a_{1,2}x_2+&\dots+a_{1,n}x_n = b_1 \\
a_{2,1}x_1+a_{2,2}x_2+&\dots+a_{2,n}x_n = b_2 \\
\vdots \\
a_{n,1}x_1+a_{n,2}x_2+&\dots+a_{n,n}x_n = b_n,
\end{align*}
where all $x_i,a_{i,j},b_i \in \mathbb{R}$, it can be written in terms of the matrix $A:=(a_{i,j})$ and the vectors $\mathbf{x}:=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $\mathbf{b}:=(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ as
$$A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}.$$
However, we could also consider the complement of the solution set for $\mathbf{x}$ through the inequality
$$A\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{b}.$$
Is there a way to find generators for the set of solutions of the above inequality? Or even a way to express it algebraically without having to consider all the possible combinations of equalities and inequalities in the system? Furthermore, could the solution (if it exists) be generalized to non-linear systems?

My motivation is to define the union, intersection and complement of the solution sets of systems. The former two are farily straight-forward, but I'm having trouble with the latter. If you have any suggestions of resources that could be helpful, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: what do you mean by "generators" here? certainly the space of solutions to $A\,x \neq b$ doesn't form a vector space in the natural way. But there are ways of characterizing the space of solutions without necessarily writing "$x$ such that $A\,x \neq b$". It also isn't clear what you mean by "all possible combinations of equalities and inequalities in the system."

Comment: @RollenD'Souza by "generators", I mean a finite set of vectors, possibly containing free variables in their components, that describes the solution set for the inequality. As for the second part, what I meant is that, to have an $\mathbf{x}$ such that $A\mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{b}$, at least one of the equalities of the original system must be false. So a "brute force" way to determine a solution to the inequality would be to find the solution set of the $2^n-1$ different systems that could be created by replacing some subset of the equalities by inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Solutions $A\,x = b$ are a translation of the vector space $\mathrm{ker}(A).$ It suffices to come up with all vectors that lift us away from this affine subspace, and we can use non-zero vectors in $\mathrm{im}(A^\top)$ to do that. It isn't clear it can be generalized, since there is rarely algebraic structure on solutions to nonlinear equations, and we are leveraging some important properties of linear algebra to make this work.

Longer:
Clearly when there does not exist a $p$ so that $A\,p = b,$ then the entire space of solutions to $A\,x\neq b$ is $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Generating that set is straightforward.

Instead, suppose there exists a $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ so that
$$
A\,p = b.
$$
It is well-understood then that the entire space of solutions to $A\,x  = b$ is the set
$$
\mathscr{S}(A;b) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon x - p \in \mathrm{ker}(A) \}.$$

What you want is $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \mathscr{S}(A;b),$ i.e. all those vectors that, when multiplied by $A,$ do not equal $b.$ This amounts to expressing all those vectors that "offset" from the affine subspace $\mathscr{S}(A;b).$ This is a straightforward application of,

$$\mathbb{R}^n = \mathrm{ker}(A) \oplus \mathrm{im}(A^\top).$$

Recognizing that $\mathscr{S}(A;b)$ is just a translation of the vector subspace $\mathrm{ker}(A)$ by the vector $p,$ it suffices to take any vector in $\mathscr{S}(A;b)$ and add a *non-zero* vector in $\mathrm{im}(A^\top).$

Let me do this explicitly. Write a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that,
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{ker}(A) &= \mathrm{span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_{n-r}\},\\
\mathrm{im}(A^\top) &= \mathrm{span}\{v_{1}, \ldots, v_r\}.
\end{aligned}$$

Let $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n-r}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-r}$ be an arbitrary vector of real numbers, and let $\beta = (\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_r) \in \mathbb{R}^{r} \setminus \{0\}$ be in the punctured real space (removing the origin, so all non-zero vectors).
Then any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ taking the form,
$$ v = p + \sum_{i = 1}^{n - r} \alpha_i\,u_{i} + \sum_{i = 1}^{r} \beta_i\,v_i,$$
solves the inequality
$$A\,v \neq b.$$

That is easy enough to verify computationally, but the question you may have is  "is this actually all possible solutions?" Suppose that $q$ solves,
$$
A\,q \neq b.
$$
Equivalently,
$$
A\,(q - p + p) \neq b,
$$
or,
$$
A\,(q - p) \neq 0.
$$
Therefore, $q - p \notin \mathrm{ker}(A).$ But, because $q - p \in \mathbb{R}^n = \mathrm{ker}(A)\oplus \mathrm{im}(A^\top)$,
$$q - p = \sum_{i = 1}^{n - r} \alpha_i\,u_{i} + \sum_{i = 1}^{r} \beta_i\,v_i$$
for some $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i.$ It follows that at least one of the $\beta_i$ is non-zero.